# What does the Whether Man teach Milo in "The Phantom Tollbooth"?

Tags: character-analysis, symbolism, the-phantom-tollbooth, norton-juster

Everything in the Lands Beyond teaches Milo something, so his first encounter, the Whether Man, what does he teach Milo?

Milo confuses the 'Whether' man with the 'Weather' man, when he introduces himself. and then it is followed by a question from the Whether man about the weather, then followed by a cloud raining only on him. Is this just a coincidence or did Norton Juster mean anything by associating a weather reference to the Whether Man?

Moreover, the Whether Man asks Milo if he thinks it will rain and then rushes in his house and gets an umbrella. Despite it being sunny, Milo witnesses a cloud raining only on the Whether Man, why is that? What does that symbolize?

Other than this, every kingdom in the Lands Beyond is at fault in some way due to the absence of Rhyme and Reason. Could we say that the Whether Man is also affected by that, keeping in mind his behaviour and way of speech. Has the absence of Rhyme and Reason also affected the Land of Expectations overall?